# Equivalent of Java code in objective C: Integer.parseInt(frameTagAsString, 16);

Tags: java, objective-c, hex

I would like to have an easy correct equivalent of this Java code:

```
Integer.parseInt(frameTagAsString, 16);
```

Where `frameTagAsString` is a string with length 2.

While I know how to parse a hex string into an int value

```
    unsigned int uint;
    NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: frameTagAsString];
    [pScanner scanHexInt: &uint];
    frameType = uint;
```

The issue is that it just parses even invalid strings into int values.

I need to catch these invalid cases explicitly. So I tried this:

```
 @try {
    // the String to int conversion happens here
    //frameType = Integer.parseInt(frameTagAsString, 16);
    unsigned int uint;
    NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: frameTagAsString];
    [pScanner scanHexInt: &uint];
    frameType = uint;

} @catch (NSException* nfe) {
    frameType = -1;
}
```

And since the objective C code just parses any string it will not correctly catch the invalid cases.

Is there no other alternative than to write my own conversion routine in objective-C that also checks for a valid hex string ?

ps of course I could convert the value back into a hex string and then compare with the original string - but my question is if there isn't an already build in routine that I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSScanner` will return `NO` if it doesn't find a valid string, according to its validation rules:

> The hexadecimal integer representation may optionally be preceded by 0x or 0X.

Here is sample code that demonstrates this:

```
    NSString *valid1 = @"ae";
    NSString *valid2 = @"0xae";
    NSString *valid3 = @"0Xae";
    NSString *invalid1 = @"ze";
    NSString *invalid2 = @"hello";

    void (^scanBlock)(NSString *) = ^(NSString *toScan) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:toScan];
        UInt32 parsed = 0;
        BOOL success = [scanner scanHexInt:&parsed];
        NSLog(
            @"Scanner %@ able to scan the string %@. parsed's value is %x",
            success ? @"was" : @"wasn't",
            toScan,
            parsed);
    };

    for (NSString *valid in @[ valid1, valid2, valid3]) {
        scanBlock(valid);
    }

    for (NSString *invalid in @[invalid1, invalid2]) {
        scanBlock(invalid);
    }
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Scanner was able to scan the string ae. parsed's value is ae
Scanner was able to scan the string 0xae. parsed's value is ae
Scanner was able to scan the string 0Xae. parsed's value is ae
Scanner wasn't able to scan the string ze. parsed's value is 0
Scanner wasn't able to scan the string hello. parsed's value is 0
```

However, due to its flexible nature, `NSScanner` won't apply validation rules beyond that of its immediate scan position. It also perceives as invalid some strings that others may consider valid hex strings. For example:

```
    NSString *greyArea1 = @"x23";
    NSString *greyArea2 = @"artichoke";
    NSString *greyArea3 = @"1z";
    NSString *greyArea4 = @"     a3";

    for (NSString *grey in @[greyArea1, greyArea2, greyArea3, greyArea4]) {
        scanBlock(grey);
    }
```

Even though these strings are invalid for an application that expects input to strictly be a string representing a hexadecimal number and nothing else, and some people may consider "x23" a valid hex string, this code gives the following output:

```
Scanner wasn't able to scan the string x23. parsed's value is 0
Scanner was able to scan the string artichoke. parsed's value is a
Scanner was able to scan the string 1z. parsed's value is 1
Scanner was able to scan the string      a3. parsed's value is a3
```

Since Java's `Integer` class and `NSScanner` have such different purposes, the rules they apply to validate strings are much different, and I think that's the root of your problem. If you do wish to use `NSScanner`, then you will have to apply validation rules that make sense for your application that would interfere with `NSScanner`'s general operation.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
uint = [frameTagAsString intValue];
```

according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html), it returns 0 on invalid string inputs.

Alternatively, since 0 is still a valid number and it's not very indicative you could use a regex.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(\\d+)$"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:NULL];

NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:frameTagAsString
                                            options:0
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match) {
    uint = [frameTagAsString substringWithRange:[match range]];
} else {
    // error
}
```

Comment: thanks, but 0 is a valid number again and could also have been the valid hex value

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you.

```
int value;
NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:@"123abc456"];
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
[pScanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:charSet];
while(![pScanner isAtEnd]) {
    if([pScanner scanInt: &value])
        NSLog(@"%d", value);
}
```

Outputs:

```
2013-03-29 20:29:12.648 scanner.m.uQzuCBsY[3753:707] 123
2013-03-29 20:29:12.650 scanner.m.uQzuCBsY[3753:707] 456
```

`scanInt:` returns a bool saying whether it found a valid int or not.

Comment: thnaks - but amazingly complex compared to Java :-)